# Re-run all changes in Lease Collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I created several new pipelines in Azure Data Factory to process CosmosDB Change Feed (which go into Blob storage for ADF processing to on-prem SQL Server), and I'd like to "resnap" the data from the leases collection to force a full re-sync. Is there a way to do this?

For clarity, my set-up is:

Change Feed -> 
Azure Function to process the changes -> Blob Storage to hold the JSON documents -> Azure Data Factory which picks up the Blob Storage documents and maps them to on-prem SQL Server stored proc inserts/updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and simplest way is to do it is to simply delete the lease documents and make sure that the `StartFromBeginning` setting is set to true. Once restarted the change feed service will recreate the leases (if the appropriate setting is configured to true) and reprocess all the documents.

The other way to do so is to update every single lease document and reset the Continuation token "checkpoint" to null, however I don't recommend this method since you might accidentally miss a lease which can lead to issues.

Comment: I'm trying your first solution now, thanks for your answer! Let me report back what I find, but it looks like it's working

Comment: You can also check [this blog post](https://medium.com/asos-techblog/synchronising-azure-cosmos-db-into-redis-cache-using-azure-functions-621d00813ccf) of mine explaining a similar scenario but with Redis as the end destination. Check the bottom section "Bonus round — filling up the Redis Cache from scratch".